# How to specify environment variables in Apache site config for Django?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

How do you specify environment variables for an Apache site?

I have a multi-tenant Django site being served by Apache+ModWSGI. Each site uses the same Django code, but their settings differ slightly. An environment variable tells Django which settings to load. Currently, I'm getting a separate `wsgi_<site_name>.py` file, containing the variable appropriate for each site, but this violate the DRY rule. I'd like to, instead, put this variable in the Apache site config, and use a single `wsgi.py` file for all sites.

I can't find much info on how to do this. I found this [one old blog post](https://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/nov/12/apache-environment-variables-and-mod_wsgi/) suggesting I could use the Apache config syntax:

```
SetEnv SITE somename
```

along with a wsgi file like:

```
import os, sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..'))

sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(environ, start_response):
  os.environ['SITE'] = environ['SITE']
  return _application(environ, start_response)
```

but this has no effect. If I print out the `SITE` variable, Django never receives the value "somename" and displays the default value.

As far as I can tell the [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html) component is still supported, and I've confirmed it's both installed and enabled on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was calling `get_wsgi_application()` too early. The correct code is:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

def application(environ, start_response):
    os.environ['SITE'] = environ['SITE']
    _application = get_wsgi_application()
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```